# Why did log4j2 used LMAX Disruptor in Async logger instead of any other built in non blocking data structure?

Tags: logging, log4j2

I am going through Asynchronous logging in different loggers. I happened to see log4j2's async logger in detail. It is using **LMAX Disruptor** internally to store events. Why are they using LMAX Disruptor instead of any built-in non-blocking data structure of java?

Comment: Log4j2 [needs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) a [garbage-free](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/garbagefree.html) bounded queue with good latency/throughput. What's a built-in queue that has those characteristics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async Loggers, based on the LMAX Disruptor, were [introduced in Log4j 2.0-beta-5](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.0-beta5) in April 2013. Log4j2 at the time required Java 6. The only built-in non-blocking datastructure that I am aware of in Java 6 is `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Why the Disruptor? Reading the [LMAX Disruptor white paper](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf), I learned that queues are generally not optimal data structure for high-performance inter-thread communication, because there is *always contention on the head or the tail* of the queue.

LMAX created a better design, and found in [their performance tests](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Performance-Results) that the LMAX Disruptor vastly outperformed `ArrayBlockingQueue`. They did not test `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` because it is unbounded and would blow up the producer (out of memory error) in scenarios where there is a slow consumer (which is quite common).

I don't have data from my own tests at the time, but I remember that `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` was better than `ArrayBlockingQueue`, something like 2x higher throughput (my memory of the exact numbers is vague). So LMAX Disruptor was still significantly faster, and there was much less variance around the results. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` sometimes had worse results than `ArrayBlockingQueue`, quite strange.

LMAX Disruptor performance was stable, much faster than other components, and it was bounded, so we would not run out of memory if an application would use a slow consumer like logging to a database or the console.

As the [Async Loggers performance page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance), and the overall Log4j2 [performance page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) shows, the use of LMAX Disruptor put Log4j2 miles ahead of competing offerings in terms of performance, certainly at the time when Log4j2 was first released.